# What is meant by Lemon Experience?

Tags: mac

I am not sure that is this the place to ask this question, but I heard of Lemon Experience on Mac. What does it mean? is it some hardware failure or software issue?

Comment: I've been a regular Mac user for seven years and have never once heard the term "Lemon Experience" used in regard to Apple or Mac products.

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, you can maybe try the [English SE site](http://english.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Can you provide a source to the use of this terminology? I know what it means to "buy a lemon" or "own a lemon", but "a Lemon Experience" is a new one to me.

Comment: Another long time Mac user who has never heard of that phrase in conjunction with Apple.

Comment: Add me to the list of ignorants. I've never heard of it. Maybe it's related to Apples and Oranges? :)

Comment: Perhaps your looking for a [Lemon Parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemon_Parser_Generator) (part of SQLite) or the LEMON C++ library: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LEMON_(C%2B%2B_library) ?

Comment: The answers below are correct. I _have_ heard it used to describe a mac. (Once, and only once). It is used to describe an unlucky experience where a switcher's first purchase is one of the rare cases that there are a lot of problems in a short time. The result is often that the user gets frustrated and switches back to Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the phrase you've heard is probably in reference to a faulty/dud piece of equipment, as per the definition:

```
"(informal) a person or thing, esp. an automobile,
regarded as unsatisfactory, disappointing, or feeble"
```

I don't think it's something Apple or Mac specific, and in fact is probably more often used with non Apple products.

Comment: +1. Searching `"lemon Experience" Apple Mac OS` brings up the slang for a lot of things, not just Mac.

Comment: This and bmike's answers are probably the correct answer, it's the general understanding of what it means to own/buy a lemon, I'm still very curious about the specific source(s) that caused the OP to ask the question.

Answer (score 0):

In the US there is a body of law known as "[lemon laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemon_law)" that arose from car sales. Basically, if a car is sold to a consumer and the manufacturer is unable to remedy a specific covered fault after the consumer has presented the vehicle for numerous repair attempts, these laws provide additional protection to consumers.

Perhaps this question might be migrated to a consumer law answer board unless someone can uncover a mac connection.